# Python mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a relative newbie in python but I wanted to plot some graphs but I get this error --> ***ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have shapes (1,) and (1, 738, 7)***
How can I remove the column that is too much.
Kind regards :)

```
    import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

BTC_EUR = yf.Ticker("BTC-EUR")
hist = [BTC_EUR.history(period="max")]
rec = BTC_EUR.recommendations
info = BTC_EUR.info
price = BTC_EUR.info['regularMarketPrice']
supply = BTC_EUR.info['circulatingSupply']
market_cap = price*supply
moskau_zeit = 1/price*100000000
fiftytwoweeks = BTC_EUR.info['fiftyTwoWeekLow']
price_since_fiftytwoweeks = (price/fiftytwoweeks-1)*100
day_low = BTC_EUR.info['dayLow']
day_high = BTC_EUR.info['dayHigh']

print(hist)
print(price)
#print(BTC_EUR.major_holders)

#for key,value in info.items():                  
 #print(key, ":", value) 


if price < day_low:
  print(f"Buy! The price is at {price:,.2f} EUR/BTC")
  
if price > day_high:
 print(f"Dont buy now, too expensive! The price is at {price:,.2f} EUR/BTC")

if price > day_low and price < day_high:
 print(f"Wait, market isnt moving rn! The price is at {price:,.2f} EUR/BTC")
 
print(f"There are {supply:,.2f} BTC in circulation. This is {supply/21000000*100:,.2f}% of the aggregate supply.")
print(f"The market cap is {market_cap:,.2f} high")
print(f"The moskau time is {moskau_zeit:,.2f} SAT/EUR")
print(f"The price of BTC has risen by {price_since_fiftytwoweeks:,.2f}% since the 52 weeks-low of {fiftytwoweeks:,.2f} euros")
plt.plot(hist)
plt.figure(figsize= (12,12))
plt.xlabel('Zeit')
plt.ylabel('Kurspreis')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You don't need to "remove" anything, you can just use slicing: `plt.plot(hist[:2])`. But without knowing the data it's hard to tell how you need to transform it / which part to select.

Comment: `hist = [BTC_EUR.history(period="max")]` should be `hist = BTC_EUR.history(period="max")` and `plt.figure(figsize= (12,12))` goes before `plt.plot(hist)`

Comment: @mapf That is actually not correct, because `hist` is a list with a dataframe inside.

Comment: It shows Date, Ope, High, Dividens, Sotck Splits. I tried your advice but it didnt work, still same error.

Comment: There are multiple comments, which one are your referring to? I tested my comment and know it works

Comment: @trenton aaah thanks! now its plotting I was trying smth and forgott to remove it. ^^

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney fair enough. I was only judging from the error message.

Comment: You can just do `hist.plot(figsize=(12, 12), xlabel='Zeit', ylabel='Kurspreis', logy=True)`, providing you've removed the dataframe from the list. [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eOaW.png)

Comment: Im using notepad++ what do you use?

Comment: Mostly Jupyter Lab. PyCharm when I want an standard IDE.

Comment: `hist.plot(figsize=(12, 12), xlabel='Zeit', ylabel='Kurspreis', logy=True, subplots=True)` [graphs](https://imgur.com/a/cV5g2il) one more: how I cut out Dividens and Stock Splits? :D

Comment: `hist.iloc[:, :-2].plot(figsize=(12, 12), xlabel='Zeit', ylabel='Kurspreis', logy=True, subplots=True)`

Comment: Thanks! :D Is it possible to scale the Y-axis with the actual  prices? now it gives me just 10^4.

Comment: `plt.xticks(range(min(), max()+1))
plt.yticks(range(min(), max()+1))` maybe like this? but how do I get the values?